# Can kafka-streams listen to two topics and wait for the other event that matches the id and once it receives post it to another topic?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, node-kafka-streams

I have a two different kafka topics which has same field **Id** in it. Can a stream listen to these two topics and write a new message to the third topic when it receives same id on both those topics?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can perform a windowed join.
Maybe this will help :
https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api#kstream-kstream-join

> For stream-stream joins it’s important to highlight that a new input record on one side will produce a join output for each matching record on the other side, and there can be multiple such matching records in a given join window